# HTC Evo touch screen and keyboard malfunctioning. Where can I find an RUU file, or how else can I restore to factory settings or fix these problems?

Tags: screen, rom, htc-evo, ruu

I bought a an HTC EVO Shift 4G phone on eBay, but parts of the screen don't respond to touch. Different parts of the screen don't respond at different times. Also, sometimes when you type on the keyboard, the wrong letters come out.  I tried searching all over the web for a ruu (if I got that right?) to set the software back to factory settings, but can't find any. This is after trying to do a hard reset, which didn't help.  I've already spent hours trying to figure this out. Can this phone be fixed, and how?

Comment: Does the phone have warranty? If yes get it replaced.

Comment: no warranty, but thanks! any other suggestions?

Comment: You've already tried resetting and all so it can be concluded that it is a hardware problem. You can fix this by replacing the screen.